# Pymongo Dynamically generate find query

Tags: python, mongodb, filter, pymongo, dynamicquery

I am trying to use `find_one` operator to fetch results from mongodb:

My document structure is as below:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"600e6f592944ccc5790f1a9e"},
        "user_id":"user_1",
        "device_access":[
                {"device_id":"DT002","access_type":"r"},
                {"device_id":"DT007","access_type":"rm"},
                {"device_id":"DT009","access_type":"rt"},
           ]
        }
```

I have created my filter query as below

```
    filter={'user_id': 'user_1','device_access.device_id': 'DT002'},
           {'device_access': {'$elemMatch': {'device_id': 'DT002'}}}
```

But Pymongo returns **None**, when used in a function as below:

```
#Model.py
#this function in turn calls the pymongo find_one function  
 def test(self):
    doc = self.__find(filter)
    print(doc)

 def __find(self, key):
    device_document = self._db.get_single_data(COLLECTION_NAME, key)
    return device_document

 #Database.py
 def get_single_data(self, collection, key):
    db_collection = self._db[collection]
    document = db_collection.find_one(key)
    return document
```

.
Could you let me know what might be wrong here ?

Comment: Try adding some print statements in the code to see what's happening

Comment: @Gibbs ,when this filter is passed directly to 'find_one' operator I get the results , but when it passed via a func it only returns 'none'. can you let me know if there is a different way to build this filter query. ,this one is a type(filter) :'tuple of dict items', I also tried converting it to str(filter)[1:-1] but same result

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are incorrect. Try:

```
filter = {'user_id': 'user_1','device_access.device_id': 'DT002', 'device_access': {'$elemMatch': {'device_id': 'DT002'}}}
```

Also `filter` is a built-in function in python so you're better off using a different variable name.

Comment: The second dict enclosed by brackets is a `Projection document`, used to display only specific fields:<br/>

A MongoShell example for the above query:

`db.users_device.findOne({'user_id':'user_1','device_access.device_id':'DT002'},{'device_access':{'$elemMatch':{'device_id':'DT002'}}})`

Output: `{ _id: ObjectId("600e6f592944ccc5790f1a9e"),  device_access: [ { device_id: 'DT002', access_type: 'rw' } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out on why the above query is returning **None**

The `**filter**` variable, as you could see, is `,`comma separated. This is considered by python internally as `*Tuple of Dictionary values*` and when the `filter` var is passed on over another function it considers as a separate argument, though it never throws any exception in this case.

In order to overcome this, I now added `*args` to all the function calls that is being passed over.

```
#Model.py
#this function in turn calls the pymongo find_one function  
 def test(self):
    doc = self.__find(filter)
    print(doc)

 def __find(self, key, *args):
    device_document = self._db.get_single_data(COLLECTION_NAME, key, *args)
    return device_document

 #Database.py
 def get_single_data(self, collection, key, *args):
    db_collection = self._db[collection]
    document = db_collection.find_one(key, *args)
    return document
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Why not just use 2 variables; one for fllter, one for projection?

Comment: @BellyBuster, thanks for the suggestions, will try that out as well.